# Is this a valid way of taking the derivative.

Tags: calculus

$\def\lnx{\ln x}\def\lny{\ln y}$
The problem is  find $f'(x)$ of $f(x)=x^{2\lnx}$

Here's my approach:

Let $$y=x^{2\lnx}$$
$$\lny=\lnx^{2\lnx}$$
$$\lny=2\lnx\cdot\lnx$$
$$\lny=2(\lnx)^{2}$$
$${d\over dx}\lny = {d\over dx}2(\lnx)^{2}$$
$${1\over y}*y' = 2*2lnx*{1\over x}$$
$$y'=y*{4\lnx\over x}$$
$$y'=x^{2\lnx}*{4\lnx\over x}$$

My professor did it by taking the $\ln$ of $x^{2\lnx}$ and then using base $e$ something like 
$$e^{\lnx^{2\lnx}}$$ 
Is my approach valid?

Comment: Yes. $ { } { } $

Comment: Youre a calculus student. Right? Are you unaware at this point that a single problem can be solved in several different ways?

Comment: I asked because 1, I wasn't sure if all steps were correct. Reason why I was unsure was because points were taken off for solving this problem this way on an exam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly correct.  Note that one final simplification is possible; $$y' = 4 x^{-1 + 2 \log x} \log x.$$

Comment: Any idea why my professor wouldn't want me to do it this way? He took 2 points off the exam and said I should have done it his way.

Comment: I don't know.  The two methods are mathematically equivalent, so unless there is a **mathematical** reason why the professor can justify that your approach is incorrect, I don't see why deducting points for your answer would be reasonable.

Comment: My guess is that the professor wants to encourage students to solve math problems involving more complicated powers in a standard way: always convert to base e. That is indeed good advice! However, in my opinion the professor should respect alternative methods such as yours.